# Error with getElementById(id).remove() in IE11

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, removechild

I have this code:

```
document.getElementById(id).remove();
```

But, IE give me an error with this function. Do you know an other way for make this remove?

Comment: Only the "edge" version of IE supports this. Always a good idea to check the manual. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: what is id's value, and how does the html look like?

Comment: Error: "Object does not support property or method 'remove' "

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
var child = document.getElementById(id);
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

Comment: thanks. nice working for me.

Answer (score 19):

Use the [pollyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```
if (!('remove' in Element.prototype)) {
    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
        if (this.parentNode) {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    };
}
```